# Percent of rational coordinates that is a multiple of another point on the elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, computational-number-theory

Consider elliptic curves $E:= y^2=x^3+Ax+B $ (A, B are integers) which have points $P, Q$ with rational coordinates and satisfy $P=[n]Q, n>1$. Now consider the below problem:

Input: Rational coordinates = $P$.

Output: Integers $A, B, n$ (when $n>1$), and rational coordinates $Q,$ $$OR,$$

$$Return \; 0.$$

now we want to know how many points $P$ will have a curve satisfying above condition, so -

What is the percent of rational points $P$ that will not return $0$ among all rational points pair? is there anything in the literature related to the above problem?

**Note:** In this post/problem description, to be rational point on $E$ only $x$ coordinate has to be rational, rational y-coordinate is not mandatory.

A related problem is asked [on math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4694550/613063).

Comment: The set of points $P$ with rational $x$-coordinate is a countable collection of vertical lines. How do you propose to define percentages in such a set?

Comment: If only the $x$ coordinate is rational do you only input the $x$ coordinate? Also why is the rational $y$ coordinate not mandatory?

Comment: @GerryMyerson for example, in integers 50% integers are even, 50 % integers are negative... thus probability of finding an integer even or negative is... of course in above posted case, we might not be calculate exactly, but an lower/upper bound is expected.

Comment: @WillSawin to relax the problem, both $x, y$ rational are more restricted than only rational $x$, I reckon, thus it might be easier, that is why.

Comment: @WillSawin  based on my earlier comment, now you can decide whether you accept both or only $x$ coordinate rational and then calculate what percent of such $P$ exists.

Comment: Defining a probability measure on the integers is trickier than you might think, Consider, and even trickier on the set under consideration here. But on the integers: consider the set that contains all the integers with an odd number of digits – the integers $1$ through $9$, $100$ through $999$, $10000$ through $99999$, and so on. What percentage of integers are in that set?

Comment: @GerryMyerson i admit it is difficult, I am not expecting a complete solution here, but any meaningful direction will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's worth asking: _why_ do you want this thing? Is there something in particular you're hoping to learn about the rational points, or the measure itself, or? This feels like one step along the path of a larger question and having a better sense of that larger question can help people with providing a meaningful answer to this one.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki to exclude or include rational number in the designing of an cryptographic algorithm, should I include the motivation in the post?

Comment: @FelipeVoloch  would you please refer to something (article, book) in detail? You can post answer showing if you want, thanks.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch if $A, B$ are rational how do you find that? is it trivial? please refer to a book/document where I can find the detail, if don't lay out the detail.

Comment: I had posted an answer but I noticed it has a bug.